# get reference of abstract class method in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, abstract-class

In my application, I have one abstract class for getting multilanguage phrases.

It works fine in my all of Views, but now I need that method for my controllers too.

Here is the code of that Abstract class.

```
public abstract class SurveyViewPage<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public string Phrases(string Phrase)
    {
        List<MultilanguagePhrasesVM> List_Multilanguage = StaticCacheLocaleStringResource.CheckForCachedPhrases();
        var PhraseValue = List_Multilanguage.Where(m => m.LanguagePhrase == Phrase).FirstOrDefault();

        if (PhraseValue == null)
        {
            return Phrase;
        }
        else
        {
            return PhraseValue.LanguagePhrase_Value;
        }
    }
}
```

> **What I Want?**

**I want to access this Phrases() method in my controllers too.**

I tried few ways to achieve this but none of them were significantly worked.

can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Move that code into a shared class that you can instantiate or make it static.

Comment: This looks like bad design. Move Pharses to another helper class.

Comment: @DavidG  
 
Initially I think of that way, but isn't there that I can achieve same functionality that right now I am accessing in Views, like a class System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can redesign code in this way:

```
public abstract class SurveyViewPage<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public string Phrases(string Phrase)
    {
        return SomeHelper.Phrases(Phrase);
    }
}

public static class SomeHelper
{
    public static string Phrases(string Phrase)
    {
        List<MultilanguagePhrasesVM> List_Multilanguage = StaticCacheLocaleStringResource.CheckForCachedPhrases();
        var PhraseValue = List_Multilanguage.Where(m => m.LanguagePhrase == Phrase).FirstOrDefault();

        if (PhraseValue == null)
        {
            return Phrase;
        }
        else
        {
            return PhraseValue.LanguagePhrase_Value;
        }
    }
}
```

And use `SomeHelper` in controllers.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access it from a controller, you need to move the method to another class. As an easy approach, you can create a static helper class and implement the method as a static method, so that you can access it this way from both the controller and your views:

```
MyStaticClass.Phrases("phrase")
```

Comment: Initially I think of that way, but isn't there that I can achieve same functionality that right now I am accessing in Views, like a class  System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>..

Comment: Of course you can just make the method static in the abstract class, but in comparison to a special helper class this creates a connection from controller to views that is not obvious. I'd prefer the static helper class.